# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. when CORS is enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm having some issues with React consuming my web API. I'm receiving the following error when submitting a POST request:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7078/api/v1/Authentication/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

However, CORS seems to be setup. I followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0:

Program.cs

```
using HealthChecks.UI.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using WatchDog;
using AspNetCoreRateLimit;
using PetTracker.StartupConfig;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using PetTracker.HealthChecks;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.AddServices();
builder.Services.AddCors(opts =>
{
    opts.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
    {
        policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseWatchDogExceptionLogger();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(opts =>
    {
        opts.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();


app.MapControllers();
app.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
{
    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
});
app.MapHealthChecksUI();
app.UseWatchDog(opts =>
{
    opts.WatchPageUsername = app.Configuration.GetValue<string>("WatchDog:Username");
    opts.WatchPagePassword = app.Configuration.GetValue<string>("WatchDog:Password");
    opts.Blacklist = "health";
});
app.UseResponseCaching();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseIpRateLimiting();

app.Run();
```

Login.js

```
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
function LoginModal(props) {
  const [userName, handleUserName] = useState("");
  const [password, handlePassword] = useState("");

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "https://localhost:7078/api/v1/Authentication/token",
        JSON.stringify({ userName, password }),
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    } catch (err) {}
  }

  return (
//Modal
  );
}

export default LoginModal;
```

I must be missing something. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Using browser dev tools, are you able to see the preflight request? If so, might be worth showing that request/response details in your question. Also, presumably debugging, you may see CORS related information shown in the debug output window. If so, add that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. My application was running in development mode, so I needed to add `app.UseCors();` in this if statement within Program.cs:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(opts =>
    {
        opts.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    });
    app.UseCors();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your frontend is working from 'http://localhost:3000' and your backend is 'https://localhost:7078'. Because of different ports these are two different origins, so CORS forbids to access localhost:7078 from localhost:3000 and you need to either disable cors in dev mode, explicitly allow access from localhost:3000 in your backend, something like:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                      });
});
```

Or you can also setup webpack dev server (or whatever you use for development) to proxy requests from localhost:3000 to localhost:7078 and change your frontend, so it will call localhost:3000, but webpack web server will proxy such requests to your backend to localhost:3000 (and in release environment you can do similarly with real web server like nginx or whatever you use)